# How can I update a row in Android

Tags: android, web-services, sqlite

I've a web service that fetches data from a remote server. If the data from the web service is different from the existing (local sqlite database), i want to update the data on the local database. I used the sql statement:

```
UPDATE MyTable SET Col1='Val1', Col2='Val2', Col3=Val3 WHERE _id=1 AND (Col1<>'Val1' OR Col2<>'Val2' OR Col3<>Val3)
```

and tried to execute the query using execSQL but it's not working for me. Can anybody suggest a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Your query will only update at most one row, because of `WHERE _id=1`.